getInstalledRelatedApps() returning empty for a Windows App store app in React application
I have a single page react application, where I am trying to check if a Windows 365 application has been installed. The application that I am trying to check for is - https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n1f85v9t8bn , which is the windows 365 application.
I have a manifest.json as following:
{
  "name": "name-of-app",
  "short_name": "short-name",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "id": "MicrosoftCorporationII.Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe",
      "url": "https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n1f85v9t8bn"
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true
}


the code I am trying to check is as following:
// Extend the Navigator interface to include getInstalledRelatedApps
declare global {
    interface Navigator {
      getInstalledRelatedApps: () => Promise<{ platform: string; id: string; url: string }[]>;
    }
  }

and
const checkAppInstalled = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
        if ('getInstalledRelatedApps' in navigator) {
            try {
                return await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps()
                    .then(installedApps => {
                        const isInstalled = installedApps.some(
                            (app) => app.platform === 'windows' && app.id === 'MicrosoftCorporationII.Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe' // Use PFN here
                        );
    
                        if (isInstalled) {
                            console.log('Windows 365 app is installed!');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Windows 365 app is not installed.');
                        }
                        return isInstalled;
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error checking installed apps:', error);
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    };

installedApps is coming out as empty. Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe is the id of the app windows machines

I have tried changing the ID as following:

"related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "id": "MicrosoftCorporationII.Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe",
      "url": "https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n1f85v9t8bn"
    }
  ],

"related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "id": "MicrosoftCorporationII.Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftCorporationII.Windows365",
      "url": "https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n1f85v9t8bn"
    }
  ],

"related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "id": "Windows365_8wekyb3d8bbwe",
      "url": "https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n1f85v9t8bn"
    }
  ],

None of these worked for me :(
